# Do I need more than my current 3 tables in order to create the relationships explained in my post?

Tags: mysql, database, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a clone of a very popular application called `Discord` which allows people to communicate over voice, video, and text.

Discord allows every user to create their own servers and invite people to them. In order to allow users to create servers, I first created 2 tables - `users` and `servers`

```
Users table:
id, username, password
```

And

```
Servers table:
id, name, image, userId
```

So the relationship between these 2 tables is that a `user` can create and have many `servers` and a `server` belongs to a `user`. So far, so good.

Once a `server` is created, `users` can join the `server` as members of that `server`. A `user` can join as many `servers` as he wants and a `server` can have many members. I achieved this by creating a `server_users` junction table and a many-to-many relationship between `users` and `servers`:

```
Server_Users table:
id, userId, serverId
```

This works fine, however, I'm not sure if the logic behind the many-to-many relationship between `users` and `servers` is sound. To me it seems like I'm applying 2 relationships between users and servers and I don't know if this is correct. Maybe I need more tables to make the relationships clear?

1. `User` has many `servers` and a `server` belongs to a `user` ( Because a `user` is the owner/creator of a `server`, and the `server` belongs to only 1 `user` - his creator )
2. `Server` has many `users` and `users` have many `servers` ( As in every `server` can have many members and every member can be a part of many servers )

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good design, almost a textbook example. The goal is that the tables are in [normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms), which is the case here.

An alternate design also with three tables, if you would like to "merge" the two relationships, is to also use Server_Users to store the user who owns the server, marked as such with a boolean column. However, I think it is more efficient how you did it with a foreign key (userId), as you will only need one join for the 1-to-N relationship.

I would also add that the design of the table is not only motivated by getting this right "theoretically", but also by your use case. Picking a design depends on the kinds of queries that you will run against the database. If you list all users on a server including the owner, but never the owner alone, then the alternate approach may be faster.

Another aspect is integrity constraints: do you require that the owner of the server is also a member of that server, or is it fully independent? This also influences the design.

An alternative in the context of large quantities of data that do not get updated often, is to denormalize everything, by nesting the users (replicated) inside the server tuples.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approaches are good.

As discribed before it's depending on your use cases or future functions.

In my opinion you have this possibilities:

**Possibility 1**

*user*

- id
- username
- password

*server*

- id
- name
- image
- userId
- adminId (references user id of admin/owner/creator)

*user_server*

- id
- userId
- serverId

**Possibility 2**

*user*

- id
- username
- password

*server*

- id
- name
- image
- userId

*user_server*

- id
- userId
- serverId
- admin (null if not an admin and true if an admin/owner/creator)

**Possibility 3**

*user*

- id
- username
- password

*server*

- id
- name
- image
- userId
- roleId (1=normal user, 2=admin,3=moderator)

*user_server*

- id
- userId
- serverId

*role*

- id
- rolename

With possibility 1 you are limited to one owner of a server.
With possibility 2 you could add a "admin flag" to each user wich is allowed to manage the server. (like in chat groups of a messanger where exists multiple group admins)
With possibility 3 you could add a system to manage the rights of the corresponding users.